# BIBO stability on a accumulator system from oppenheimer book

Tags: math, stability

[image]

[image]

Is this stability correct?. If im getting it right, x[k] has a bounded value(M), so the interval between the summatory times this value tells the max value of output. But shouldn't it be |n - no + 1|M?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9np.png). The end result is the same(not stable) but the interval is what I wrote in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9np.png). Don't know if I explained myself well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since \$|n-n_0 +1|>|n-n_0|\$, since all \$n-n_0\$ are non-negative, the statement of all the inequality signs is accurate. Lugging around the extra \$+1\$ doesn't help!

Comment: yes, it is more clear and helpful with n-n0 but is my logic right?

Comment: I don't understand that question? Whether it's \$|n-n_0 + 1|\$ or \$|n-n_0|\$ makes no difference, and hence, "shouldn't it be?" is not an answerable question. In this *very* strict sense of the word logic, no your logic is hence not correct, as you're asking to confirm the answer to an inanswerable question, but in the wider sense of the word, you're not saying anything different than the inequation from the book.

Comment: If n0 = 1 and n = 3, there's [x[1], x[2], x[3]] (3 values), |n−n0| = 2 values and |n−n0+1| = 3 values. This is my problem.

Comment: but: there's no problem there!

Comment: Sorry for offending you. You don't need to answer my questions.

Comment: I'm not offended, I just don't see the same problem as you :)